# pytest fixtures naming as a variable

Tags: pytest, pytest-fixtures

I have two pytest selenium fixtures:

- wd - webdriver fixture (widely used for all webend tests)
- wdwire - webdriverwire fixture (for request/response manipulating of webend)

Both work as they should, but I need to have a variable named like the fixture to get it to work. So it means two separate functions or renaming. I have lots of test and would like to
reuse the same code, just changing the fixture and function parameter.

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("wdwire")
def test01_userportal_security(self, wdwire):
  """ using wdwire webdriver """
  url = tools.urls.urls['user-portal']['url']
  wdwire.get(url)
  :
```

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("wd")
def test01_userportal_security(self, wd):
  """ using standard webdriver """
  url = tools.urls.urls['user-portal']['url']
  wd.get(url)
  :
```

Any way to add a variable to remap wd/wdwire so they can use the same function with a parameter change?

Tried:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("wdwire")
def test01_userportal_security(self, wd=wdwire):
  """ using wdwire webdriver """
  url = tools.urls.urls['user-portal']['url']
  wd.get(url)
  :
```

gives: `NameError: name 'wd' is not defined`

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("wdwire")
def test01_userportal_security(self, wd="wdwire"):
  """ using wdwire webdriver """
  url = tools.urls.urls['user-portal']['url']
  wd.get(url)
  :
```

gives: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: What do your fixtures look like?  What if you had a 3rd fixture, for use in the test, that returns either the wdwire or wd, based on whatever your conditional is.